# How do I use the GFAPI class from Gravity Forms?

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

How do I use the GFAPI class from Gravity Forms? I want to get all the entries from a given form. But nothing seems to work.. Do I need to import/include/require the class?

```php
<?php

getEntries();

function getEntries() {
    $form_id = 73;
    $search_criteria = array();
    $entries = GFAPI::get_entries($form_id, $search_criteria);
    exit(var_dump($entries));
}
```

When I open the file, it doens't work, and I have a feeling it's because it can't find the class.

In the GF docs, it says: "The API Functions are automatically included when Gravity Forms loads and they will be available by the time add-ons load. The API class is called GFAPI and it can be found in /plugins/gravityforms/includes/api.php.".

Comment: What does “when I open the file” mean? Is this supposed to be a stand-alone script, or does this execute within the WP context? _“and I have a feeling it's because it can't find the class”_ - enable proper PHP error reporting resp. the WP debug mode, so that you can replace such vague “feelings” with _certainty_.

Answer (score 0):

$entries = GFAPI::get_entries( '73' );

It probably isn't working due to the $search_criteria variable.  If no results are found with your search, you won't get any results.  The parameter is optional.